# Equivalent of FIRST() and LAST() in Impala

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, select, impala

My data from different Sensor units is comming with unix_time stam in Hadoop. It is quite easy to get the first and last value of each day in SQL using the FIRST and LAST statement, as given below. Here I am getting the temperature at the start and at the end of the day.

```
SELECT unit, FIRST(Temp) as Start_Day_Value, LAST(Temp) as End_Day_Value
FROM Sensor_Data.Table
WHERE cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN "2021-01-05 00:00:00" AND "2021-01-05 23:59:59"
GROUP BY unit
ORDER BY unit;
```

Is there any equivalent command in the IMPALA so that I can get the first and last value of the each column as  am getting in SQL.

Comment: Given that MySQL doesn't support `FIRST()`/`LAST()`, I'm baffled on where this code is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem in the following way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.unit, u.initial_temp, u.final_temp, u.initial_p, u.final_p
FROM(SELECT unit,
first_value(temperature) OVER(PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts DESC) as final_temp,
first_value(temperature) OVER(PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts ASC) as initial_temp,
first_value(pressure) OVER(PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts DESC) as final_p,
first_value(pressure) OVER(PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts ASC) as initial_p
FROM Sensor_Data.Table
WHERE cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN "2020-12-11 00:00:00" AND "2020-12-11 23:59:59"
) AS u
ORDER BY unit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL has a `FIRST_VALUE()` *window* function, but not an equivalent for aggregation.  So, one method to do what you want in Impala -- or just about any other database -- is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unit,
       FIRST_VALUE(Temp) OVER (PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts) as Start_Day_Value, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Temp) OVER (PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts DESC) as End_Day_Value
FROM Sensor_Data.Table
WHERE cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) >= '2021-01-05' AND 
      cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) < '2021-01-06'
ORDER BY unit;
```

Note that I also simplified the date comparison.

Note:  I'm not sure that `cast()` works (I would expect the code to use `from_timestamp()`).  But that is not what you are asking.

EDIT:

In Impala, you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT u.unit,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_asc = 1 THEN temp END) as first_temp,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_asc = 1 THEN temp END) as lasst_temp
FROM (SELECT unit,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts) as seqnum_asc, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY ts desc) as seqnum_desc _Day_Value
      FROM Sensor_Data.Table
      WHERE cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) >= '2021-01-05' AND 
            cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) < '2021-01-06'
     ) u
GROUP BY unit
ORDER BY unit;
```

Comment: When I am trying the abve code then I am getting the following Error:

**AnalysisException: cannot combine SELECT DISTINCT with analytic functions**

It is not allowing me to add DISTINCT in the SELECT statement. Any idea how I can resolve this ?

Comment: @ZeeshanShareef . . . Wow.  I've never seen a database with that restriction.  A subquery should fix it.  If not, there are alternative approaches that use aggregation instead.

Comment: It is quite common in Impala that you cannot use DISTINCT with the Analytical functions.
@GordonLinoff

Comment: With your sub-query the problem is still not solved.
Can you recommend any other solution ?

Comment: @ZeeshanShareef . . . I added the solution I would *normally* use.  I just recommended using `FIRST_VALUE()` because it was closest to your original query.